How to use Kotlin backing field with Channel and Flow?
I am playing with the new backing field feature introduced in Kotlin 2.0, however I am encountering some problem when using it on data type that is not a superclass/subclass of one and another.
private val _youTubeVideosState = Channel<YouTubeVideosState>()

val youTubeVideosState = _youTubeVideosState.receiveAsFlow()

How to convert this with using backing field? I tried the below but wasn't able to access the send() method of Channel.
val youTubeVideosState: Flow<YouTubeVideosState>
    field = Channel<YouTubeVideosState>().receiveAsFlow()

If I tried the below it is complaining about the type not being superclass of subclass.
val youTubeVideosState: Flow<YouTubeVideosState>
        field = Channel<YouTubeVideosState>()


Are you sure the first one doesn't compile and it is not just the IDE that doesn't recognize the new syntax? Please compare my answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78529945/6216216

@Leviathan it won't compile since the field is already a Flow thus the send method which is from Channel is no longer available. Also tried with initializer and seems it will not be supported or I am misunderstanding it?

This doesn’t make sense to do. A Flow and Channel are not in a hierarchical relationship. The property type must be a supertype of the field type, because the way this feature works is that the value in the field is merely upcast to the type of the property. It’s still the same instance/reference.
receiveAsFlow() creates a new instance of a different class. That instance has to be stored somewhere, and it cannot be in the same backing field as the channel, so two properties are necessary. A property can’t have two backing fields.

Thanks so this will never be valid or at least for now.

I also have another question related to backing field here
